# When you willingly lower spell resistance, and discover a harmful spell can you resume it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spell-resistance

If a player is willing to lower their spell resistance to someone casting a spell on them, what choices do they have open to them?

If they have spellcraft they have the ability to tell what spell is being cast, but at what point, and could they resume their SR fast enough to try and be protected?

Would the SR be down regardless of what they were trying to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Not usually

[Spell resistance](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#spell-resistance)

> A creature can voluntarily lower its spell resistance. Doing so is a standard action that does not provoke an attack of opportunity. Once a creature lowers its resistance, it remains down until the creature's next turn. At the beginning of the creature's next turn, the creature's spell resistance automatically returns unless the creature intentionally keeps it down (also a standard action that does not provoke an attack of opportunity).

So, unless the casting time of the spell goes beyond the start of the creature's next turn, its spell resistance stays down while the spell is being cast.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88212/23650) by @ShadowKras shows that by [readying](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#ready) its standard action to drop SR when it detects a benign spell being cast, a creature can reduce its risk. Its SR is then down until that initiative count on the following round, however. So it's a trade-off, though since SR isn't easily detectable, it's generally moderately safe to do.

Comment: It's as much metagaming as lowering your resistances to obtain a non-harmful spell.

Comment: How is that any different from: "i will wait for them to come closer before i stab with my sword" ?

Comment: It's an action that you are delaying until some condition happens. It's the definition of the Delay action rule. If the condition does not happen, you lose your action, akin to the enemy never getting closer for you to stab them.

Comment: You are confusing two rules, Readying an Action and Delaying an Action.
Delaying you act after them, regardless of what their action was. Readying you act before them, based on a predefined condition. If the condition was not met, you lost your action. That's the price of this "metagaming".

Comment: Also, initiative is simply the order that things happen (regardless of combat), characters may not know what the order is, but they know that after something JUST cast a spell on them, they can't cast another for a few seconds. It's simply a measurement of time.

Comment: The delaying suggestion won't work. If you complete a readied action, your initiative changes to the point at which you took said action. Therefore, the target's turn would move to just before the caster no matter where the target originally was in the initiative order relative to the caster. Because of this, the SR would still be down for a full round of actions.

Comment: @MikeKellogg You are correct. I'll change that; I was focusing on beating the system. Still, ShadowKras's readying reduces unhealthy exposure.

Answer (score 3):

### No.

Lowering the spell resistance lasts until the character's next round.

But otherwise, you can **Ready an Action** saying that you will lower your spell resistance if you see that it's not a harmful spell being cast on you. Since lowering your SR is also a *Standard Action*, it qualifies for readying.

Comment: Oh, thats a good idea and one I should keep in mind